# How to replace "nodejs" for a variable into "search pattern" awk

Tags: awk

Hi friends I need replace with a variable in **search pattern** with awk, I am reading all questions similar but none explain how to use a variable in the part **"search pattern"**. The basic format of an awk command is:

```
awk '/search_pattern/ { action_to_take_on_matches; another_action; }' file_to_parse
```

The problem I have a simple script of search , from a site. **¿How to replace "nodejs" for a variable into "search pattern"?**

**This is my script in bash** (work but I can't use variable in awk)

```
#!/bin/sh
searchname=nodejs


mojito=$(curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=$searchname |  awk -F/ '/>nodejs</{print $2}')
echo $mojito
```

Comment: sorry, but it's had to understand your intention with "How to replace "nodejs" for a variable into "search pattern". Consider editing your question to show sample data retrieved from `curl`, then what you need as final output, and what your are currently getting for output.

Comment: 1. You'll almost always have fewer problems if you quote variables as you use them, i.e. `...name_filter="$searchname". 2. Assuming you mean to supply `"$searchname"` also to awk, instead of having a hard-coded value, do `awk -F/ '/'"${searchname}"'{print $2}'`.  Good luck.

Comment: @sheller, thanks but doesn't work, said `awk: line ord. 1: regular expression ^ unfinished`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk -v patt="$searchname" '$0 ~ patt{ print $0}'
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# searchname="nodejs"
sat:~# echo -e "sample text\nthis have nodejs value" | awk -v patt="$searchname" '$0 ~ patt{ print $0}'
this have nodejs value
```

Comment: Thanks worked! only I changed: `mojito=$(curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=$searchname | awk -F/ -v patt=">$searchname<" '$0 ~ patt{ print $2}')`